# Python script self reload it's self when a keyboard key pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how can i write the line of code which will auto restart the script from the start. Example :- if i press Q then the python script must start all over again.

Comment: Use the keyboard module (`pip install keyboard`) and combine it with `os.execl`?

Comment: You need to show us the script or at least the smallest amount of it that allows us to provide an answer.